# Umbraco 5 - Adding content pages from another application

Tags: umbraco5

I'm trying to take a look at Umbraco 5, and trying to figure out how to add content from an outside application.  In v4 I would have done something like the following,

```
        var documentType = DocumentType.GetByAlias(UmbracoDocumentType.Country.ToString());
        var parentId = DocumentFinder.GetDefaultParentIdForDocumentType(documentType.Alias);
        var docs = Document.GetDocumentsOfDocumentType(documentType.Id);
        var list = docs.Select(doc => Convert.ToInt32(doc.getProperty("externalId").Value)).ToList();

        string name;
        Document document;
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (list.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["Id"])))
            {
                document = DocumentFinder.GetDocumentByExternalId(dataRow.Field<int>("Id"), documentType.Id);
                document.getProperty("name").Value = dataRow["Name"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                name = dataRow["Name"].ToString();
                if (name == string.Empty) continue;
                document = Document.MakeNew(name, documentType, administratorAsAuthor, parentId);
                document.getProperty("externalId").Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["Id"]);
                document.getProperty("name").Value = dataRow["Name"].ToString();
            }

            try
            {
                document.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionManager.Handle(ex);
            }
        }
```

But in v5 there are no such things, and I have searched and searched and found nothing that could help me, even put a post on thier forum, and no responses yet.  So, I wanted to post here to see if anyone else might know how this done now.

I know that its still Beta, but I think that there should be a way.

Thanks,
Andrew